# Solve easy equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Can anyone please help me with solving this equation; thanks!

$$
\displaystyle \frac{d+7}{3}+4\quad=\quad -\frac{5d}{4}
$$

---

**My Steps**

$1.$ Multiplied both sides by $3$ and $4$ to get rid of the division.

Giving me: $4(d + 7 + 4) = 3(-5d)$

**$2.$** Multiplied out the brackets.

Giving me: $4d + 28 + 16 = -15d$

**$3.$** Collected like terms.

Giving me: $4d + 44 = -15$d

$44 = -19d$

$d = -2.31$

---

$d = -4$ apparently but I'm not sure how to get this answer

Comment: Step 1 is wrong. In particular the left hand side.

Comment: 1. should be $4(d+7+12) = \dots $

Comment: Can you please explain why that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

multiplying by $12$ we get
$$4(d+7)+48=-15d$$
this is equivalent to
$$4d+28+48=-15d$$
$$19d=-76$$
$$d=-4$$

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to multiply the $4$ on the LHS by $3$ in your first step. Your equation after step $1$ should read:
$$4(d+7+\color{red}{12})=3(-5d)$$
The rest is fine.

Comment: $d$ is on the right side

Comment: I multiplied $4 x 4 = 16$, why do you have to multiply $3 x 4 = 12$?

Comment: @PerfectNutter In your first step, when you multiplied through by $3$, you effectively removed the denominator of the fraction and multiplied the RHS by $3$, but you forgot to multiply the $4$ on the LHS by $3$.

Comment: @PerfectNutter I mean the following: $$3\times\left(\dfrac{d+7}{3}+4\right)=3\times\dfrac{d+7}{3}+3\times 4=d+7+12$$

Answer (score 3):

You have a (very common) mistake at step $1$. If you multiply by $3$ and after by $4$ you get
$$4\times 3\left(\displaystyle \frac{d+7}{3}+4\right)\quad=4\times 3 \left(-\frac{5d}{4}\right)$$
$$4\left(d+7+\color{red}{ 3\times}4\right)=4\times 3 \left(-\frac{5d}{4}\right)$$